# Build custom library without header dependency

Tags: c++, qt

I made a small application in Qt, for sending and receiving messages from/to a RabbitMQ broker.

I made a library containing a RabbitMQ publisher and consumer, which in turn uses the AMQP library [here](https://github.com/mbroadst/qamqp). 
Now everytime I need to use this library in an application, I need to copy the two .lib files (qamqp, RabbitMQLib), plus about 10 header files, and then add them in my .pro file (through `LIBS` and `INCLUDEPATH`).

I made a similar project in C#, but there I only needed two .dlls, and that was it.

My question is : how can I make the same with Qt? Just one or two .lib files, which will be included in the application that needs them, and that's it, no need for 10 additional header files.

Comment: The compiler needs to know about the symbols you use from the lib, there's no way around it. You could dlopen()/LoadLibrary the DLLs, but then you have to work with function pointers and symbol lookup.Just use the headers, it's the most convenient and robust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can totally do this. You do not actually need these headers (using them is just usefull) - all you really need is to declare all objects (types, functions, variables) you are actually using. So, if you have a lot of headers, but use, say, only one function, all you need is to add this function declaration before you actually use it (may be, adding something like `__declspec(dllimport)`, or, if using Qt - `Q_DECL_IMPORT`).

But, if the only problem you are facing, is adding all these files to your pro-file, a better solution here would be to write a pri-file, like this:

**mylib.pri**

```
INCLUDEPATH   += $$PWD/headers
DEPENDPATH    += $$PWD/headers

HEADERS += \
    $$PWD/headers/header1.h \
    ...
    $$PWD/headers/header10.h

LIBS += -L$$PWD/libs -lqamqp -lRabbitMQLib
```

and include it to your pro-file:

```
include($$PATH_TO_COMMON_LIBS/mylib/mylib.pri)
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is not the header inclusion ( I do that with a single INCLUDEPATH); the problem is that I have to copy all the headers whenever I use the library somewhere. I'd like to only copy the library. The `Q_DECL_IMPORT` sounds like it's the right thing, but I couldn't get it to work. I have a `RabbitMQPublisher`class in my library, which is marked for export, like this `Q_DECL_EXPORT RabbitMQPublisher`. However, when using it in a client, I did a forward declaration `class Q_DECL_IMPORT RabbitMQPublisher;`, but the compiler says that `class has no constructors`.

Comment: When importing a class, you need to declare at least all methods, you are using. Not sure, if it's enough, though, 'cause usually you declare all class members. That is why using headers is usefull - you do not need to copy all this info. Also, if it is acceptable, you could merge several headers in one. Btw, if you are using version control system, instead of copying you could use externals.